# Why would a NullReferenceException get thrown because my method returns null?

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

As shown below I have a method in my class that returns null as expected when it does not successfully read a value.  I assume that the object "test" would just be set to NULL but for some reason an error is getting thrown.

[image]

I don't understand why this would throw an error...

```
private string myNullFunction() { return null; }
private void myFunction()
{
  object test = myNullFunction();
}
```

when this does not...

```
private void myFunction()
{
  object test = null;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `null.Value` would do?

Comment: probably `m_xml` or `m_xml.Read(...)` is `null`

Comment: @MattBurland In response to your flag... That other question is VERY broad.  Looking at that question I would have never realized what my actual problem was.  Only when you said "null.Value" did I realize the null was coming from Read() and not .Value.

Comment: Your question is very broad and exact like the first example in the answer to the dupe: `ref1.ref2.ref3.member` And the answer is exactly the same. You have to make sure every step of your chain is not null. Every time you use a `.` you have to consider if the thing you are putting that `.` on is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code does not actually throw an exception. The real issue is shown in the code snippet above the exception dialog: m_xml.Read is returning null, but you are trying to access the Value property.

Answer (score 2):

Read function is returning null. That's why null reference exception is there.

Comment: I was just about to tell Matt to put that in an answer!  ;)  That was exactly what the problem was...  I just was not thinking it through.  I wish the IDE would say something like that...  "The Read() method is null" or something.